# How to use add_settings_error in register_setting callback

Tags: errors

```
public function database_name_check($input){
    //debug
    add_settings_error('notice', 'lol', 'lol');
    if($this->wpdb->get_var($this->wpdb->prepare('SHOW DATABASES LIKE %s', $input)) == $input)
        return $input;
    else{
        add_settings_error('notice', 'lol', 'lol');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I can not understand why the error does not exceed, any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [`add_settings_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error) prototype.

```
add_settings_error( $setting, $code, $message, $type );
```

The first argument is your settings name/key -- or if your setting is on another page (eg `general`) it should be the page key. The second is whatever you'd like to add to the ID attribute, then error/updated message, and finally type.  It doesn't work because you're using it incorrectly.

So you probably want...

```
<?php
add_settings_error(
    'your_setting_key', // whatever you registered in `register_setting
    'a_code_here', // doesn't really mater
    __('This is the message itself', 'wpse'),
    'error', // error or notice works to make things pretty
);
```

You also need to tell WordPress to display your settings errors.  If it's on a custom page, you'll need to include [`settings_errors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_errors) in the callback.

```
settings_errors('your_setting_key');
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3XsexNcg here is full example, but still not working with or without `die()`.

Comment: See my edit, make sure you include `settings_errors` in your admin page callback.

Comment: yes, already found this solution, but thanks.